# How to add a dynamic scroll view in onClick and edit something in table row

Tags: java, android

I created a table row that if I click the grid item it shows this table row and I need this table row Scrollable ,I want to add a dynamic scroll view in this code in table layout,But it crashed When I use the onclick, Could any one help me for this as I need also if I add item with the same type It will increase the nuber in the Qty column for ex: if I click on the eggs roll 2 times it will add in the Qty column 2 not adding another row like in the pic and also the same in the total price [Here's the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/478jO.png) sorry for my bad english

```
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Result tr
                TableRow tr_head2 = new TableRow(GridDynamic.this);
                tr_head2.setId(10);
                tr_head2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fab_label_background));
                tr_head2.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                tr_head2.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

                TextView label_category2 = new TextView(GridDynamic.this);
                label_category2.setId(20);
                label_category2.setText("1");
                label_category2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                label_category2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                label_category2.setTextSize(18);
                label_category2.setPadding(20, 3, 20, 3);
                tr_head2.addView(label_category2);// add the column to the table row here

                TextView label_quantity_amount2 = new TextView(GridDynamic.this);
                label_quantity_amount2.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
                label_quantity_amount2.setText(alphabets.get(arg2).get("Name").toString()); // set the text for the header
                label_quantity_amount2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                label_quantity_amount2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                label_quantity_amount2.setTextSize(18);
                label_quantity_amount2.setPadding(20, 3, 20, 3); // set the padding (if required)
                tr_head2.addView(label_quantity_amount2); // add the column to the table row here

                TextView label_total_price_amount2 = new TextView(GridDynamic.this);
                label_total_price_amount2.setId(22);// define id that must be unique
                label_total_price_amount2.setText(alphabets.get(arg2).get("Price").toString()); // set the text for the header
                label_total_price_amount2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                label_total_price_amount2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                label_total_price_amount2.setTextSize(18);
                label_total_price_amount2.setPadding(20, 3, 20, 3); // set the padding (if required)
                tr_head2.addView(label_total_price_amount2); // add the column to the table row here

                tableLayout.addView(tr_head2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(GridDynamic.this);
                scroll.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                scroll.addView(tr_head2);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), alphabets.get(arg2).get("Item_ID").toString()+
                                " "+alphabets.get(arg2).get("Name").toString()+
                        " "+alphabets.get(arg2).get("Price").toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just advice not related to problem - use [java code convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf). And if you want to receive help - post stack trace of exception.

Comment: thanks for your help I gonna try this